# CREATE DATABASE failed at stsadm -o extendvs

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Anyone pls give me suggestion.

I am trying to create a new web application at sharepoint.

But cannot create from sharepoint central admin ... error occured "Unknown Error".

so I try to create with stsadm -o extendvs ... at that time error occured..

Directory lookup for the file "F:\MSSQL\DATA\WSS_Content_Internet_NewProd.mdf" f
ailed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specifie
d.).
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check relat
ed errors.

CREATE DATABASE failed at stsadm -o extendvs

pls give me any advice...

Answer (score 0):

Check the ULS logs for detailed error messages. F:\MSSQL path that you have mentioned, does exist on the server, right?

Also, do you appropriate permissions?

Comment: with extendvs,  i am using the database server from another machine .. but I have appropritate permission ... at the command I put -databaseserver "PRDDB01" -databasename "WSS_Content_Internet_NewProd"  ... databaseserver is from another machine ... thanks